# How can i fix my discord bot oauth2 section?

Tags: php, authentication, discord

Even though I did everything right, when I try to connect my account, I keep getting this error.

{"message":"Couldn't get user object!"}{"message":"Couldn't get guilds object!"}
how can i fix that problem?

[Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lees.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWp7u.png)

Although I press Authorize, I see that my account is not connected to the bot in Authorized Applications

how can i fix that problem?

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . "/../config.php");
require_once(__DIR__ . "/discord_functions.php");

$USR_username; 
$USR_discrim; 
$USR_id; 
$USR_SERVER = false; 
$USR_guild_active = "true"; 
$redirect_uri = BASE_URL."/actions/register.php";
$DISCORD_LOGIN_URL = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=".OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID."&redirect_uri=".BASE_URL."%2Factions%2Fregister.php&response_type=code&scope=identify%20email%20guilds"; 

session_start();

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Authorization Error"));
    } elseif (isset($_GET["code"])) {
        
        $data = array(
                "client_id" => OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
                "client_secret" => OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
                "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
                "code" => $_GET["code"],
                "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri,
                "scope" => "identify guilds"
            );
            
            $token = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_URL, "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token");
            curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));       
            curl_setopt($token, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $resp = json_decode(curl_exec($token));
            curl_close($token);
        
        // Get user object
        if (isset($resp->access_token)) {
            $access_token = $resp->access_token;
            $info_request = "https://discord.com/api/users/@me";
            $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer {$access_token}");
            
            $info = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($info, CURLOPT_URL, $info_request);
            curl_setopt($info, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($info, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            
            $user = json_decode(curl_exec($info));
            curl_close($info);
            $USR_username = $user->username;
            $USR_discrim = $user->discriminator;
            $USR_id = $user->id;
            $USR_discrim = $user->discriminator;
            
            $rank = checkDiscordPermissions($USR_id);

        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("message" => "Couldn't get user object!"));
        }
        
        // Get guilds
        if (isset($resp->access_token)) {
            $access_token = $resp->access_token;
            $info_request = "https://discord.com/api/users/@me/guilds";
            $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer {$access_token}");
            
            $info = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($info, CURLOPT_URL, $info_request);
            curl_setopt($info, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($info, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($info, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($info, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($info, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            
            $guilds = curl_exec($info);
            curl_close($info);
            
            // Convert JSON string to Array
            $NewArray = json_decode($guilds, true);
            foreach ($NewArray as $key => $value) {
                if($value["id"] == GUILD_ID)
                {
                    $USR_SERVER = true;
                    
                }else{}
            }
            
            if($USR_SERVER == false)
            {
                 header("Location: ../login.php?unauthorised");
            }
            else
            {
                // THIS IS WHERE THEY ARE SUCCESSFULLY IN THE GROUP AND WE CAN ADD THEM TO THE DB OR LOG THEM STRAIGHT IN IF THEY ARE IN ALREADY
                try{
                    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
                } catch(PDOException $ex)
                {
                    echo json_encode(array("response" => "400", "message" => "Missing Parameters"));
                }
                
                $result = $pdo->query("SELECT discordid FROM users WHERE discordid='$USR_id'");
                $exisits = false;
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                    // SETUP THEIR SESSION STUFF AND TAKE THEM DIRECTLY TO THE PANEL
                    $exisits = true;                    
                    setupAndSendOnline();
                }
                
                if($exisits == false)
                {
                    if($rank == 0 || $rank == "0") {
                        header("Location: ../login.php?unauthorised");
                    } else {
                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, discordid, rank, avatar) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                        $result = $stmt->execute(array($USR_username, $USR_id, "0", "AVATAR STRING"));
                        setupAndSendOnline();
                    }
                }
            }
            
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("message" => "Couldn't get guilds object!"));
        }
        
        
    } else {
        header("Location:" . $DISCORD_LOGIN_URL);
    }
    
function setupAndSendOnline(){
    
    global $USR_id, $USR_username, $USR_discrim;
    
    //DO TOMS FUNCTIONS HERE
    $avatar = getDiscordAvatarByID($USR_id, "512", "gif");
    $rank = checkDiscordPermissions($USR_id);
    
    //ASSIGN THE SESSIONS
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'YES';
    $_SESSION['staffid'] = $USR_id;
    $_SESSION['staffname'] = $USR_username;
    $_SESSION['staffrank'] = $rank; 
    $_SESSION['staffavatar'] = $avatar;
    $_SESSION['stafftag'] = $USR_discrim;
    
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    } catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo json_encode(array("response" => "400", "message" => "Missing Parameters"));
    }
    
    // UPDATE THE PLAYERS AVATAR WITH TOMS AWESOME FUNCTION HERE
    $result = $pdo->query("UPDATE users SET name='$USR_username', avatar='$avatar', rank='$rank' WHERE discordid='$USR_id'");
    
    if($rank == 0 || $rank == "0")
    {
        header("Location: ../login.php?unauthorised");
    } else {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
}
    
?>
```

Comment: Start by checking what actual response you got from the token endpoint API call.